# How can I show that Mathematics is not all about numbers?

Tags: self-learning

My goal is to be able to show that many concepts in Mathematics do not necessarily need numbers, and they can be formalized for sets that do not involve numbers. To explain what I mean, suppose I define the following set of objects:

$$
G = \{phone,volleyball,shoe,water \ bottle\}
$$

I want to know what questions I need to answer so that I can be able to treat set $G$ the same as the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$. More precisely, I want to be able to perform the basic operations (addition, subtraction, etc), I want to be able to define functions from the set $G$ to another arbitrary set of objects, and I want to be able to differentiate and integrate these functions.

However, as I have no formal background in Mathematics, I'm interested in resources that can help me do this. Honestly, I am not even sure where to start, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

For future reference, based on the comments, I found a free book called [Abstract Algebra: Theory and Applications](http://abstract.ups.edu/) by Thomas W. Judson that I think is helpful.

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Do you want to understand the definition of a topology? The main body of your question suggests that you might want to look into some introductory abstract algebra. It is not a new idea to endow abstract sets with operations analagous to the arithmetic operations you learnt in school.

Comment: As I said, I have no idea where to start. Any suggestions on how I can rephrase my question?

Comment: I think my best advise would be to pick up an easy beginner text on abstract algebra and start to read. You will soon discover that $\mathbb{R}$ is an example of a field. A field is an algebraic structure with certain properties, other such structures are monoids, groups and rings. When you understand I guess you have achieved your goal of seeing that mathematics does not rely heavily on numbers. You will also see that your set $G$ is fundamentally different from $\mathbb{R}$. However, you could impose an algebraic structure on $G$ as well.

Comment: You can't do arithmetic on a topological space, unless you equip it with an algebraic structure. Things like integrals and differentials do also not exist in topological spaces per se. However, if your topological space happens to be a manifold that admits a differentiable structure, you can indeed do analysis on them. If you'd like to learn more, i'd suggest reading any comprehensive literature about *differentiable manifolds*.

Comment: Hey @Fenris, thanks a lot for the advice! Could you suggest a beginner text on abstract algebra?

Comment: @Zest, thanks for the literature reference and the explanation!

Comment: *A First Course of Abstract Algebra* by John Fraleigh is a widely used one. I am sure there are pelnty of other books as well. This YouTube channel does a lot of book reviews of mathematics texts: https://www.youtube.com/user/themathsorcerer if you want to look into some of them.

Comment: @Fenris, thanks again. Are there other fields besides abstract algebra that could help me show that Math can be applied to objects other than numbers?

Comment: Well there are several fields that do that: geometry (especially if you look into the geometry of the Greeks), graph theory, set theory, but I think abstract algebra is the best starting point to see that the "patterns" of our number system are generalizable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let do a little Frame challenging here:

> I want to know what questions I need to answer so that I can be able to treat set $G$ the same as the set of real numbers $\Bbb R$.

You can't. One characteristic of $\Bbb R$ is that it has infinitely many elements. Many of the things you do with $\Bbb R$ *require* infinitely many elements to do. But $G$ has only four elements. You can set up a lot of things on $G$ that *look* like similar operations on $\Bbb R$, but only if you do not look closely. No matter what you define on $G$, it will not be long before you discover differences in behavior from $\Bbb R$.

---

Okay, so we abandon the $G$ you defined, and instead pick one with as many elements in it as $\Bbb R$. (This is infinite - indeed a bigger infinity than even the rationals have, so it cannot be physical items. But it doesn't have to be a subset of $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ or some other acknowledged set of numbers.) Can we define operations on $G$ so that it acts just like $\Bbb R$?

Yes, in theory. Because it is infinite, how one goes about that is going to depend exactly how the set is picked. But we'll just assume that part can be worked out. What you need to define is:

- An element "$0$" of $G$ and an operation "$+$" on $G\times G$ with values in $G$ which has the properties

  1. (Additive Identity) For all $x \in G, 0 + x = x$
  2. (Additive Inverse)  For all $x \in G$ there exists a $y \in G$ with $x + y = 0$
  3. (Commutivity of Addition) For all $x, y \in G, x + y = y + x$
  4. (Associativity of Addition) For all $, y, z \in G, (x + y) + z = x + (y + z)$
- An element "$1$" of $G$, $1 \ne 0$, and an operation "$\cdot$" on $G \times G$ with values in $G$ which has the properties:

  1. (Multiplicative Identity) For all $x \in G, 1 \cdot x = x$
  2. (Multiplicative Inverse)  For all $x \in G, x \ne 0$, there exists a $y \in G$ with $x \cdot y = 1$
  3. (Commutivity of Multiplication) For all $x, y \in G, x \cdot y = y \cdot x$
  4. (Associativity of Multiplication) For all $, y, z \in G, (x \cdot y) \cdot z = x \cdot (y \cdot z)$
  5. (Distributivity of Multiplication over Addition) For all $x, y, z \in G, x\cdot(y + z) = (x\cdot y) + (x\cdot z)$
- A binary relation $\le$ between elements of $G$ satisfying

  1. (Reflexivity) For all $x\in G, x \le x$
  2. (Antisymmetry) For all $x,y \in G$, if $x \le y$ and $y \le x$, then $x = y$.
  3. (Transitivity) For all $x, y ,z \in G$, if $x \le y$ and $y \le z$, then $x \le z$.
  4. (Linearity) For all $x, y \in G$, either $x\le y$ or $y \le x$.
  5. If $x, y, z \in G$ and $x \le y$, $x + z \le y + z$.
  6. If $x, y, z \in G, z > 0$ and $x \le y$, then $x \cdot z \le y \cdot z$.
  7. (Completeness) If $A, B \subseteq G, A \ne \varnothing, B \ne \varnothing, A\cup B = G, A \cap B = \varnothing$ and for all $a \in A, b \in B, a \le b$, then there is some $x \in G$ such that if $y < x$, then $y \in A$ and if $y > x$, then $y \in B$.

(That is, if $G$ is divided into two non-empty sets $A, B$ such that all elements of $A$ are $<$ all elements of $B$, there is a point $x \in G$ where $A$ and $B$ meet. Either $A = \{r\mid r < x\}, B = \{r\mid r \ge x\}$ or $A = \{r\mid r \le x\}, B = \{r\mid r > x\}$. This property is what differentiates $\Bbb R$ from $\Bbb Q$. The sets $\{r\in \Bbb Q\mid r < \sqrt 2\}$ and $\{r\in \Bbb Q\mid r > \sqrt 2\}$ divide $\Bbb Q$ with no point in the middle.)

You get all of that done, and you have a set $G$ that can be used in every way exactly like $\Bbb R$, no matter what the elements of $G$ actually are. So you've shown that Math doesn't require numbers, right? Wrong.

This is where the frame challenge comes in. No matter what the elements of $G$ were. Now they are numbers. Defining those operations turned them into numbers. What makes $\Bbb R$ to be $\Bbb R$ is not the elements of the set. Instead, it is exactly those properties listed. It can be shown that given any two sets that meet all of those properties, you can match up the elements of one to the other in such a way that every property is perfectly preserved by the match.

This is how $\Bbb R$ is unique. You can define the same operations and properties on other sets, but all you get is something that is effectively just $\Bbb R$ again. The underlying objects do not matter.

Comment: What an elegant and detailed answer. Really enjoyed reading the last few paragraphs. My question now is: What field in Math is relevant to this kind of reasoning? Moreover, what do I need to learn so that I can come to the same conclusion that you did in the way that you did it?

Comment: The field and order properties of $\Bbb R$ are covered in detail in Introductory Real Analysis courses (which is effectively Calculus but with all the details thoroughly examimed instead of brushed over). Fields are also a subject of Abstract Algebra, and Order is a subject of Set Theory and of Topology.  The concept that what defines a mathematical object is not the elements of the set, but the constructions (functions, operations, relations, etc) built on it is common to all mathematical fields, but is developed in detail in Category theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!